# From a set of markers placed in rows with some remainders, find the smallest smallest number of markers that the set could contain.

Tags: contest-math, chinese-remainder-theorem

> If a set of markers is placed in rows of $4$ each, there are $2$ markers left over; if in rows of $5$ each, there are $3$ left over; and if in rows of $7$ there are $5$ left over. What is the smallest number of markers that the set could contain?

First I've considered $\operatorname{lcm}(4,5,7)=140$, but couldn't deduce anything from here.

I suppose that there is a simpler way to approach this, but I couldn't figure out anything except the chinese remainder theorem. I have the system of congruences $$\begin{align} x &\equiv 2 \pmod{4} \\ x &\equiv 3 \pmod{5} \\ x &\equiv 5 \pmod{7} \end{align}$$

Using the chinese remainder theorem I've managed to solve this and get that $x \equiv 138 \pmod{140}$. But I'm not sure how to *interpret* this result in the "applied" way that the problem requires.

I can write $x \equiv 138 \pmod{140}$ as $x=140k +138$ for $k \in \Bbb Z$ and since the problem asks for *smallest* I have that for $k=0, x=138$ which turns out to be correct, but I don't still quite understand how to interpret the result $x \equiv 138 \pmod{140}$.

Comment: One way of thinking about this is that you have converted the three remainder conditions into an equivalent condition. You now have the equivalent condition that the number of makers must be two less than a multiple of 140. I don't see a more applied interpretation however.

Comment: $7 - 5 = 5 - 3 = 4 - 2 = 2$. Do you see why $140 - 2 = 138$ works?